# add a column to the dataframe using a loop in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've a sample dataframe

```
id      city
1       Florida
2       Atlanta
3       Manhattan
4       Amsterdam
5       Newyork
```

I've a function

```
def my_function(x):
    y = x[::-1]
    return y
```

How can I make a for loop that uses `city` column and inserts the reversed string in a column one by one which results the below?

```
id      city       reversed_string
 1      Florida       adirolF
 2      Atlanta       atnaltA
 3      Manhattan     nattahnaM
 4      Amsterdam     madretsmA
 5      Newyork       kroyweN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that a string in Python is an iterable. Note that you do not need `apply`.

```
df['reversed_string'] = df.city.str[::-1]
```

Comment: thanks @gofvonx. I'm just looking for how to use a function iteratively. The objective is not to reverse the string, but how to use a function.

Comment: @astroboy1 Thanks for clarifying. I'd still make the point that you can very often get away with not using `apply` at all (which usually is less efficient and not what should be understood when people talk about "vectorizing").

Comment: I see i will keep in mind in the future, it's just apply was one of the more common use case when i am using pandas, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

Simple just use an apply without a for loop

```py
df['reversed_string'] = df['city'].apply(lambda x: x[::-1])
```

If you want to use it with a function

```py
def reverse_string(string):
  return string[::-1]

df['revered_string'] = df['city'].apply(reverse_string)
```

Comment: I don't think that `apply` is necessary here.

Comment: Apply might be necessary, we dont know what the actual usecase/how complicated the function is, upvoted both answer..!!

Comment: In hindsight, i'm just suggesting the one possible solutions you can take